# How do I properly invoke an onChange event fired off by filepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm using filepicker-rails, and setting this up:

```
<%= p.filepicker_field :bathroom_images, cache: true, multiple: true, onchange: "$.onFileUpload(event);" %>
```

This sets the onChange event to whatever function I throw in ([more details here](https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file-ingestion/widgets/pick))

Now here's where I have two questions: how do I need to set up my coffeescript to be invoked by this?

```
ready = ->
  console.log("ready")

  onFileUpload = (event) ->
    console.log "results of upload stored"
    window.results = event


$(document).ready ready
```

When I upload file and the event fires off, this code throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.onFileUpload is not a function
```

That's the concrete question. Here's what I'm really curious about: ok, so you tell me how to call it, what aspects of JS am I not understanding that I need to learn better in order for me to understand what's going wrong here?

I thought I was creating a variable (onFileUpload) that references the function I want to pass the event fired off by the form to. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you're asking rails to call `$.onFileUpload(event);` but you're implementing a function named `onFileUpload(event)` that lacks the '$.' part. I suggest just changing that in the rails code to `onFileUpload(event)`.

The second issue is that rails is trying to call this method on the global namespace but you're hiding it in a sub-scope that rails can't access. This happens because you wrapped all your code in a jQuery ready event and due to the way javascript works, any code inside that function it not accessible by the code outside it unless specified otherwise.

Now to fix this simply make `onFileUpload` a property of the global `window` object. I'm not a pro in coffeescript so i don't know if this is the exact way to do it, but you can fix this by changing your code to:

```
ready = ->
  console.log("ready")

  window.onFileUpload = (event) ->
    console.log "results of upload stored"
    window.results = event


$(document).ready ready
```

This should make the function onFileUpload global allowing rails to call it.